# while (now < end) doesn't end at end time it still continues in infinite Loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, datetime, loops

I'm quite new to C# and I'm using a Modified WPF application.
The problem with my program is that the loop is infinite...
while (now < end) doesn't end at end time it still continues till you terminate main process.
The program is showing Movies and pictures and therefore is different every time. Which means that now = now.AddSeconds doesn't work. Right?

startupinfo = Listbox

```
    private bool startjob() //DateTime checking for DateValue and start's if correct value.
    {
        DateTime? start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime? end = DateTimePicker2.Value;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        if (start == null || end == null)
        {
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("one of the pickers is empty");
        }
        else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
        {
            while (now < end)
            {
                foreach (var selected in startupinfo.SelectedItems)
                {
                    string s = selected.ToString();

                    if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
                    {

                        Process process = Process.Start(startupinfoDict[s]);
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        while (!process.HasExited)
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var selected in listBox2.SelectedItems)
                {
                    string s = selected.ToString();

                    if (listBox2Dict.ContainsKey(s))
                    {
                        Process process = Process.Start(listBox2Dict[s]);
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        while (!process.HasExited)
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying the value of `now` in the loop. It will always evaluate `now < end` to True. Hence the infinite loop

Comment: Am I supposed to use : 
while (start < end)?
Because there is an infinite loop there too.
Is there any better solution?

Comment: while (DateTimePicker1.Value <= DateTimePicker2.Value)
Doesn't work either.

Comment: I would do `Datetime.now < end.Value` and see

Comment: It works! Thanks alot! You spared me alot of time!

Answer (score 2):

You never bother to reevaluate "now" within the loop.

Comment: Am I supposed to use : 
while (start < end)?
Because there is an infinite loop there too.
Is there any better solution?

Comment: while (DateTimePicker1.Value <= DateTimePicker2.Value)
Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `now` variable never changes. You might loop this way instead:

```
while (DateTime.Now < end.Value)
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I use that one. Am I supposed to use : 
while (start < end)?
Because there is an infinite loop there too.

Comment: while (DateTimePicker1.Value <= DateTimePicker2.Value)
Doesn't work either.

Comment: @Sneakybastardd Nobody told you to try any of that code... You were told to use `DateTime.Now`, which obviously returns the value of NOW. if "Nothing happens when I use that one" then you should probably see why, maybe check the values in the `DateTimePicker`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the obvious `end.Value` instead of `end`.